# Conflict beween on-site interview for new job and urgent meeting at current workplace

Tags: interviewing

I have an on-site scheduled for tomorrow 10am-3pm.

Originally, I told my manager that I would be out for half the day for reason X.

However, I just got pulled into a high priority / mandatory meeting with stakeholders + VP on a project that I am working on (literally just got pulled into it ~16 hours before my on-site is scheduled to begin). This meeting overlaps with my interview.

I could not request a full day off just because of my current work load.

Suggestions please? I care about this company a lot (the one that I am interviewing at).

Answer (score 12):

**It would be fine to request a different time or day for the interview, just do your best to be flexible with rescheduling.** Recruiters understand that last-minute things come up. Whether it's taking a kid to a doctor's appointment or an important meeting, there are all sorts of valid reasons to reschedule an interview.

**Call the recruiter as soon as you can** (during business hours) and consider sending an email now (if it's after hours) to ask to reschedule. Be honest about the reason.

Rescheduling the interview seems like the better option than being delinquent at work. Unless you're ready to quit, your current job should be your priority.

Comment: Worth adding that although it *may* cost the OP the job opportunity (because interviewing company may not be able or willing to be flexible), that the sooner and more professionally the OP contacts the company, being as truthful as possible in the case, the better they will look. If their new job would involve taking responsibility for critical projects, it could even be seen as a major plus

Answer (score 7):

Either

- Reschedule your meeting

or

- Reschedule your interview

It is not rocket science.

The best action you could take is to reschedule the interview and let them know exactly why.  This would most likely show integrity and dedication to your work.  A good employer would recognize this as a positive trait.

Comment: is it possible to reschedule an entire on-site less than 24 hours before it is set to begin without damaging my chances at the job

Comment: @jc315 I would definitely try. Explain why - they might appreciate the fact that you're dedicated to your work.

Comment: @KeithThompson interview, not meeting. Typo.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to reschedule your interview out of loyalty to your current boss, but only when this is possible.** If it's not convenient for the recruiter/new company at all, I would still go to the interview instead of your meeting. You're exploring new jobs for a reason. Good luck!